# Partial Order on a Vector space with a Crystallographic Coxeter Group

Tags: group-theory, geometry, finite-groups, coxeter-groups

Let $V$ be a vector space, and $W$ an irreducible, crystallographic Coxeter group on $V$ with simple root system $\Pi = \{a_1 \cdots a_n \}$.
We define a partial ordering on $V$ by $u \geq v$ iff $u - v = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} k_i a_i$ with $k_i \geq 0 \forall i$. Let $x \in V$ such that the dot product of $x$ with any simple root is positive: $(x/a_i) \geq 0 \forall i$.

I want to prove that $\forall w \in W x \geq w(x)$ w.r.t the partial order defined above. My idea is to do this by induction on the length of $w$: indeed if $w$ is a simple reflection $s_i$ then we have:
$$
s_i (x) = x - 2 \dfrac{(x/a_i)}{(a_i/a_i)} a_i
$$
and thus 
$$
x - s_i (x) = 2 \dfrac{(x/a_i)}{(a_i/a_i)} a_i \geq 0
$$

However I am not sure how to proceed to prove the heredity: if I write $w = \tilde{w} s_{i}$ I obtain 
$$w(x) = \tilde{w}(x) - 2 \dfrac{(x/a_i)}{(a_i/a_i)} \tilde{w}(a_i)$$
But this seems like a dead end since $\tilde{w}(a_i)$ is not necessarily a simple root...
Any hint would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\tilde{w}(a_i)$ may not be a *simple* root, but we may assume it is a *positive* root, otherwise $\tilde{w} s_i$ could be replaced by a shorter expression. This uses the standard result that if $w a_i < 0$ then $l(w s_i) < l(w)$.

Hence $x \ge \tilde{w}(x) \ge w(x)$, the first $\ge$ by induction and the second $\ge$ by the fact that $\tilde{w}(a_i) > 0$ and $(x,a_i) \ge 0$.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense! I can't believe I didn't think of it myself.